# How can I change the name/caption of a latex table?

Tags: formatting, captions

My table names and captions are in the "classical" LaTeX format, such as "Table 1:  Caption Text", but I wanted to make it like

```
 **Table 1**
Caption Text
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! With the caption package: `\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by

```
**Table 1**
```

you mean **bold-facing** the label and its number, i.e., obtaining **Table 1**, using the `caption` package will let you achieve your formatting objective.

E.g.,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,
                     labelsep=newline,
                     skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\centering
\caption{Caption Text} 
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline 
a & b \\ c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```